# How to Instantiate a Magento helper

Tags: magento-1.9, helper

Is a good practice to instantiate a Magento help in the class constructor?

```
protected $helper 

public function __construct()
{
    $this->helper=Mage::helper('helper_name');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magentos helpers are always singletons, so it's not necessary to instantiate them. Just using `Mage::helper('helper_name')->someMethod()` should be OK.

Comment: tnx, in terms of code readability I'd like to use $this->helper. Any contraindications with my code?

Comment: Imho, no, but i try to avoid such things :) How about an wrapper method `_getHelper() { return Mage::helper ...}` and using `$this->_getHelper()` (it's not much longer)? Maybe wait for another answer?

Comment: yes was thinking about that as well.